# How much time to I have to switch outputs on a CD74HC4067 multiplexer?

Tags: design, datasheet

Looking at this [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/product/CD74HC4067), how do I determine the amount of time I have to switch between one connection and another?

It seems that as I switch from one connection to another I will go through several intermediate states as my software sequentially toggles the select pins to high and low appropriately, in principle selecting several undesired connections.

This is obviously not a problem, but how do I verify this from the datasheet?  How slowly could my processor set the pins and still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no speed requirement. So long as rise and fall times are not excessive the sequence of channel switching is of no concern to the mux. (if they are the chip will tend to draw excessive Vdd current due to the time the inputs are at intermediate voltage).

Normally you'd want to put the 4 or 5 control inputs on a single MCU port so they would all change at once anyway.

That said, whatever you connect it to may care.

Answer (score 1):

Digital inputs should rise or fall reasonably fast. As Spehro says, during transitions excess power pin currents may flow. Also, too-slow inputs may oscillate internally at a rather high frequency. HCMOS inputs can be a bit slower when supply voltage is low as indicated in the table below.
Spec sheet also says that while switching, a **break** from one select line occurs before a **make** to another select line - a span of 6ns. This no-connect span of 6ns is very likely dependent on power supply voltage too.

From the data sheet:

DC Input or Output Voltage, VI, VO . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 0V to VCC
 Input Rise and Fall Time at various VCC voltages:
 2V . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1000ns (Max)
 4.5V. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 500ns (Max)
 6V . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 400ns (Max)